# Is there a database providing information about optimum temperature and inactive temperature of enzymes?

Tags: enzymes, database, temperature

I want to know optimum and inactive temperature of some enzyme, but I can't find these information in NCBI, wiki or UniProt. So I want to know if there are some database which provide these information?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

UniProtKB has annotations for biophysical and chemical properties, such as maximal absorption, kinetic parameters, pH dependence, redox potentials and temperature dependence.
http://www.uniprot.org/help/biophysicochemical_properties

Such annotations are currently available for about 6800 reviewed entries: http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=annotation%3A%28type%3Abiophysicochemical_properties%29&sort=score

More specifically, temperature dependences is annotated in about 2000 entries: http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=annotation%3A%28type%3A%22temperature+dependence%22%29&sort=score

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a database. It is called 'BRENDA' and can be found [here](http://www.brenda-enzymes.info/index.php). It doesn't have all the information you are looking for, but it always has the links to the relevant literature, so you can look it up.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

您好, you can find more information about optimal temperatures on [Uniprot](http://www.uniprot.org/help/biophysicochemical_properties). Look under section 5 and 我爱你.